# How to restore Configuration Settings when they fail to initialize

Tags: c#, configuration

I have my program which has some Application Settings and some User Settings. On some machines my User Settings config file becomes corrupt and stops my program loading. I then log into the machine and delete the UserConfig directory stored at
`%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local\MyApp`

When my file is corrupt the error thrown is `Configuration Settings Failed To Initialize` so I was wondering if this happened in my program whether there was a way to delete the corrupt file and reset the configuration.

So far I have:

```
try
{
     var prop1= Settings.Default.prop1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var userSettingsLocation =
      Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
        "%USERPROFILE%"), "AppData","Local", "MyApp");
    if (Directory.Exists(userSettingsLocation))
    {
      DeleteDirectory(userSettingsLocation); // This is a reccursive
                                             // delete method
      // I need to reload settings
    }
}
```

This deletes the file fine but if I try to read my settings again using for example: `Settings.Reset();` I still get the same error. I need to somehow reset the configuration Settings after deleting the corrupt file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So heres the trick if anyone else wants to know:

```
try
{
     var prop1= Settings.Default.prop1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var userSettingsLocation =
      Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
        "%USERPROFILE%"), "AppData","Local", "MyApp");
    if (Directory.Exists(userSettingsLocation))
    {
         if (ex.InnerException is System.Configuration.ConfigurationException)
         {
             var settingsFile = (ex.InnerException as ConfigurationException).Filename;
             File.Delete(settingsFile);
             System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** after some trials, I think you need to restart the application after deleting the faulty config file. Here another SO thread: [C# - User Settings broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269489/c-sharp-user-settings-broken)

The last answer there is essentially the code you could use.

---

Actually *I think* you must call `Settings.Reset` after deleting the file.

By the way you should use the exception details to get the config file name causing the issue:

```
catch(Exception ex) 
{
    if(ex.InnerException is ConfigurationErrorsException)
    {

        var settingsFile = (e.InnerException as ConfigurationErrorsException).Filename;
        /* ....Your code... */

    }
}
```

string filename (()e.InnerException).Filename;

Comment: Calling `Settings.Reset()` sadly throws `settings cannot be initialized exception` again